# how to install and run osgi bundle in apache karaf

Tags: java, apache, osgi, bundle

I have a simple question.
I followed this [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2008/jw-03-osgi1.html?page=2) and created a HelloWorld osgi bundle.
How can i install and start this bundle using apache [Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.2.x/index.html)?
How can i refer to the bundle using the osgi:install command?

thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, that is another question, but here goes:

You're pretty much on the right track, I've tested the one in the Karaf developers guide you linked to (the *second* mvn call). The documentation isn't quite correct, I needed to change two things:

- The version is off, 2.2.5 does work (on my machine), changing it to 2.2.8 seemed to help.
- The package name is com.mycompany.package. As package is a keyword, that won't compile, so I've changed it to com.mycompany.bundle.

So my archetype command was:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.karaf.archetypes \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=karaf-bundle-archetype \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.2.8 \
-DgroupId=com.mycompany \
-DartifactId=com.mycompany.bundle \
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
-Dpackage=com.mycompany.bundle
```

Then I entered the newly made project folder: com.mycompany.bundle:

```
cd com.mycompany.bundle
```

And a mvn install:

```
mvn install
```

Then there is a jar file in the 'target/' folder, which you can install into the Karaf installation as I said before.

### Creating a bundle in Eclipse

- New -> Plugin Project -> Choose a name -> check the parameters -> you can use a template if you like.
- Select your project -> Export -> Plugin/Fragment -> Choose a folder

There's your jar file.

Comment: Thank you man :) That works. I have two more questions: the mvn install command will generate all the classes and the jar and a Manifest.mf in the target folder. What if I want to configure my bundle myself? Where do I have to drop the Manifest.mf file? Can i simply create a META-INF folder and drop it there? The second question: There are many tutorials and how to's of osgi tutorial on the equinox container. Since osgi is a specification it should make nearly no difference when i am using apache karaf instead of equinox right? So i can develop my bundles using Eclipse -> Plug-in Project. ???

Comment: It's a matter of taste: Either you configure your pom.xml file, and configure your pom file to generate the MANIFEST file, *or* you create your own manifest file (for example in Eclipse). It is a pretty fundamental decision: Do you want to let Maven manage your manifest file, or do you want to do it yourself, using Eclipse?

Comment: I added instructions for Eclipse

Comment: I want to use maven to manage my manifest file(s). When i follow the eclipse way i have no problem to export and import packages. Using Maven, i have no idea how this works. If I have two project bundles (both created with the mvn archtype) and i want set one bundle as a dependency of the other, i have to refer to the package in the pom file... (<import-package> tag) right? How does this work?

Comment: You'll have to configure the '<instructions>' part of your pom file. This page explains that: http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html

Comment: Can it be that this maven-bundle-plugin figures out what packages to import on its own? :-O I made a mvn install on both projects and took a look at the generated manifest.mf and there is already the right package inside the <import-package> tag. But if i specify the package on my own in the pom file i get some errors. How does maven figure out which bundle-project is relevant? o.O

Comment: I _think_ that you have to specify the bundles you want to depend on as regular Maven dependencies, but I've no in depth knowledge of that, I don't use that plugin often.

Comment: okay. guess i will figure it out :) thank you VERY much! i marked your answer as accepted. thank you

Answer (score 6):

You can just drop the bundle into the 'deploy' directory, and Karaf just notices and installs it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I now created a osgi bundle using the maven karaf-bundle-archetype: (link: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.2.x/developers-guide/archetypes.html) But I am still not able to install and run the bundle in Karaf. How can I generate a *jar file out of my bundle so that i can drop it ito the deploy directory... ?

Comment: To add it to the deploy directory run mvn clean package from the root folder of your project (Where the pom.xml resides). This will generate a jar file in the target folder. Drag and drop it to the deploy from there.

Answer (score 2):

Frank's answer helped me quite fast:
I created a bundle with this archetype:

```
    mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.karaf.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=karaf-bundle-archetype \
    -DarchetypeVersion=2.2.8 \
    -DgroupId=com.mycompany \
    -DartifactId=com.mycompany.bundle \
    -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
    -Dpackage=com.mycompany.bundle
```

Then i did a `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and `mvn install`.
After copying the generated jar into the deploy directory of my running JBoss Fuse server it printed "Starting the bundle". :-)